# User Input and Placeholder Text Alignment on Mobile

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile, browser

I am running into an issue with the alignment of user input and placeholder text on iOS version 12.4.9. I have only tested this with an iPhone 6 on Safari and Chrome and the issue is present in both browsers.

In the images below,

- `input` elements have a `red` border, whereas `::placeholder` pseudo elements have a `yellowgreen` border;
- *'NOT A PLACEHOLDER'* and *'IN'* are actual input, whereas *'DIA'* and *'EMAIL ADDRESS'* are placeholders.

---

**Here is the base styling and the result:**

```
div.bottom-container > form input,
div.bottom-container > form input::placeholder {
  height: var(--fontSize);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: var(--fontSize);
  border-radius: unset; /* for mobile only */
}
body[data-mod='mobile'] > div.bottom-container > form input {
  border: solid red 1px;
}
body[data-mod='mobile'] > div.bottom-container > form input::placeholder {
  border: solid greenyellow 1px;
}
```

[image]

---

I have been able to align the placeholder text as desired by adding the following styling. **Notably, both the `input` and the `::placeholder` must have borders for it to be aligned properly like this.**

```
body[data-mod='mobile'] > div.bottom-container > form input {
  padding: 0;                   /* new */
  line-height: var(--fontSize); /* new */
  border: solid red 1px;
}
```

[image]

---

I want to align the input like the placeholder text, but I am struggling and do not have access to a Mac and therefore the iOS developer console. (Notably, I do not own an Android device and therefore am unable to even know if the issue exists on that platform.)

From the results above, it seems as if the `input` elements are cropped and have some `padding`-like quality that cannot be altered.

I know that `display` plays a role in matching the appearance of `input` and `button` elements on mobile and I have tried fiddling around with other properties, but to no avail.

---

**Here is the base styling with the `height` removed.**

[image]

---

I suspect the issue may be due to the browsers' effecting a minimum size on `input` fields for the sake of usability or user experience. But that is just a guess. I really have no idea what is going on.

#Does anybody know what is going on or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your input in a div for example and align the input relative to the container.

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: coral;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.wrapper input {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* Uncomment following line to see input borders */
  /* border: 1px solid lawngreen; */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" value="EMAIL" />
</div>
```

Comment: But the text is still misaligned? Sorry if I was not clear, but I am looking for a way to center the user input text exactly like how the placeholder text is centered. It should be a responsive solution instead of having to continually adjust the pixel amounts with media queries.

Comment: So you mean, the placeholder is aligned not the same way as the actual text in the input, but they should both be in the center?

Comment: yes, are you unable to see the images? i have figured out how to perfectly center the placeholder text. i would like to center the user input text in the exact same way (without re- and misaligning the placeholder text, which is now perfectly centered)

Comment: I have tried out your styling on my Windows machine and my Android phone and Tablet. I could not achieve the result you show on your screenshots, where your placeholder is centered, mine has always a bigger gap to the bottom (font-size: 100px: the difference is 4px). Maybe try changing your typeface. I had for example issues with Oswald, whose letters are a bit "misaligned".
EDIT: I gave the inputs absolute positioning, the placeholder and the actual text were identical. https://jsfiddle.net/andrisjms/qyw9jgso/16/

Comment: cuz im using and taking pictures on iOS. i havent even been able to test on Android yet cuz i dont have an android device. it doesnt look too misaligned on your device. but the issue i am trying to solve is that the user input text and the placeholder text are inherently aligned differently on mobile :/